# RE-Activate the Missing Proofing Tools - MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I accidentally hit the "Never show again" option on the Missing Proofing Tools warning (stating I have something in a different language) in my MS Word document. It's important that I get this message so I know I need to fix my document for spell check to work. How do I turn this back on?

Comment: Click the “Proofing” option, and then click the “Recheck Document” option. You should be able to enable options when this run.  Please try this.

Comment: Didn't work.  I received the "This Operation resets the spelling checker..." message.  When I clicked "Yes" it did not appear to do anything.  I ran spell check again.  Re-saved and opened.  Still no change.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try a complete Repair of Office (Control Panel) , restart and try the above again

Comment: John - Thanks for the initial response and followup.  I am giving this a try now!

Comment: John - I tried that, but it did not work.  But I'm not 100% sure I did it right.

Comment: Another option (more ugly to be sure) is to make a new, test, Windows User Profile. Log into the new Windows userid and try the above. It could be a Profile issue, or the need to replace the Word Normal.dot template.

Comment: Here is a resource for replacing the normal template. Try this:  https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/fix-word-2016-normal-template/#:~:text=How%20to%20Fix%20the%20Word%202016%20Normal%20Template,menu.%20Edit%20the%20name%20to%20Normal-old.dotm%20or%20Normal-old.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately as this  a work computer and connected via MS 365, I can't do a new profile.  I will try the link you sent.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: You may need to get "work" to log in and replace Normal.dot

Comment: I was able to do the "Normal.dot" file change.  Sadly that din't work either!

Comment: You need to get "work" to service your computer.

Comment: Wish I could!  Small business.  I don't really have an IT department. And getting the "language warning popup working again" is not high on the priority list.  I appreciate your efforts to help me!

Comment: You need to get someone there to help rebuilding the computer via a Repair Install, keep nothing, and rebuild from there. Ugly I know, but nothing else has worked.